# React-select: virtualize options list

Tags: react-select, react-virtualized, react-window

What is the expected way to virtualize options list in latest version of react-select (3.1.0)?
There is [react-virtualized-select](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized-select/) but is not longer supported. Thanks.

Comment: Look at this, react-select is really flexible library
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77490448/15604836

Answer (score 3):

I finally used [react-windowed-select](https://github.com/jacobworrel/react-windowed-select) library. The [implementation](https://github.com/jacobworrel/react-windowed-select/blob/master/src/WindowedSelect.js) is quite simple though. Thanks @jacobworrel.

Comment: Only solution that solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

[react-select-virtualized](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select-virtualized) is another alternative.